# Unusual table row-sizing

Tags: html, css

I want to have an HTML table with three rows.  The center row (B) should size its height to as small as possible to fit its contents.  The top and bottom rows (A and C) should size their height to fill the rest of the height of the table *with equal heights*.

[image: Figure]

In XAML this accomplished by using a `Grid` and then giving the rows A, B, and C the heights `*`, `Auto`, and `*`, respectively.

I tried using heights `50%`, `auto`, and `50%`, respectively, in the HTML/CSS. But that causes row A to fill up half the height of the table, with B and C filling the bottom half.

**How can I get the row heights I want using HTML/CSS?**

Comment: I have never tried this because to me, this is not doable without a few lines of javascript. Not discouraging but just saying that handling height issues with plain old html/css is not easy.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height to 1em on the desired row's cells.

HTML:

```
<table class="testing">
    <tr id="one"><td>one</td></tr>
    <tr id="two"><td>two<br/>two two</td><div id="breakme"></div></tr>
    <tr id="three"><td>three</td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.testing {
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 300px;
}

#one td {
    background-color: red;
}

#two td { background-color: blue; height: 1em }

#three td { background-color: green; }

#breakme {
    background-color: pink;
    margin: 5px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/a65vn/1/

Comment: More generally, leaving the A and C rows with a height of `auto` and setting a fixed height to B will do the job.

Comment: True. 1px does the job as well. The author needed something to be able to shrink.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
  .tbl{
     display:table;
}
  .row{
     display:table-row;
}
  .height40{
     height:40%;
}
  .width0{
     width:100%;
}
  .height-main{
     height:200px;
}

</style>


<div class="tbl width0 height-main">
  <div class="row height40">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  B
  </div>
  <div class="row height40">
  C
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: you can not use 50% width for the two rows A & C because there are three rows and row B needs some space.